# What's needed in order to make my locally deployed backend accessible from the internet?

Tags: networking, backend, web-deployment, firewall

Currently I am developing a small client-server application using Spring Boot on the back-end side and Flutter for front-end, and it is my first back-end experience.

Because my back-end runs on `localhost:some-port`, I am forced to use emulator, which is quite tedious.

I want to test on a real device, so I have an idea to make back-end accessible from the global network. In order to make this happen, I opened the port on which the application is running using `sudo ufw allow *port-number*` with subsequent `sudo ufw enable` (I use Ubuntu 16.04), because I was quite sure that all I needed is this. But still, it does not work: sending a request to `http://*my-ip*:*application-port*/*endpoint*` just timeouts after several minutes, and after changing `my-ip` value to `localhost` it works OK.

What else do I need in order to make the back-end accessible from the network?

P.S.: I have static IP.

Comment: port-forward on your router

Comment: Yep, created a virtual server using my router settings and now I receive "could not get response from the server" immediately. Still, it proves that it works, I suppose. Pls create an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @moazzem all works now. Thank you! If you fire a question - Ill mark it as accepted immediately